# Not able to create a commitment

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When trying to create a commitment

```
gcloud beta compute commitments create commitment-hyper-gpus-2 --region=europe-west1 --resources=vcpu=16,memory=104 --resources-accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1 --plan 12-month --reservation=hyper-gpus-p100-2 --reservation-zone=europe-west1-d --machine-type=n1-highmem-16 --accelerator=type=nvidia-tesla-p100,count=1 --vm-count=1
```

Its giving me the below error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.commitments.create) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Quota 'COMMITTED_NVIDIA_P100_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region europe-west1
```

But, there is no quota with name COMMITTED_NVIDIA_P100_GPUS

Answer (score 1):

You will need to request a quote increase for all GPUs (global).

1. Make sure that you have setup billing and a payment method
2. Go to the Google Cloud Console Quotas page: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas
3. Under "Metric" select GPUs (all regions). This will limit the number of services displayed.
4. Select (don't click on) Compute Engine APIs.
5. Click on "EDIT QUOTAS".
6. Fill out the form.
7. Wait to either be contacted or approved or declined.

Comment: Hi, Not sure, I understand your answer. I only need P100s in europe-west1. Why do I need to increase the quota for all the GPUs across all regions. Can you please clarify me. It would be really helpful. Also, I have tried to do what you have mentioned. It gave me around 320 results for which I need to increase the quota.

Comment: You skipped step #3 which will reduce the number of items (I think to one).

Comment: Once you have a global quota, you can then see/request quotas for specific regions/services. I have never needed a region specific GPU quota, so I have not gone past just a global quota request.

Comment: This answer might help you. Basically, you have two quotas (global and regional). You have to increase the quotas for both. You have to increase the global quota first.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843598/cant-create-gcp-ai-platform-notebook-with-gpu-it-says-quota-gpus-all-regions