# Can't create GCP AI Platform Notebook with GPU. It says Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-notebook, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm trying to create an GCP AI Platform Notebook with GPUs.

When I create the notebook it gives me the error:

```
Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally
```

However, I have requested a quota increase and had it approved.

Why am I still seeing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there are two types of quotas (Regional and Global) for GPUs and you want to make sure that you've increased both of them.  You can only be allocated more GPUs if *neither* of those quotas is being exceeded.

You can increase you quota by going to the GCP console and navigating to IAM 
& admin -> Quotas

More detailed instructions on requesting a quota increase here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Also @vincent has posted screen shots of exactly how to request global GPU quota here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53678838/21539